# Notification not shown even if service is running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, notifications

I am building an application which does some work when a specific wifi network is connected. To check if my wifi network is connected i am running a background service which runs a thread of infinite loop inside it. The thread checks for wifi connection is active or not. If yes, then it displays the notification and keeps the notification until wifi is disconnected. I cannot find the better approach to check for my connection asynchronously. The problems I am facing is as follows:
If service is already running and I connect to network i get a notification. Now I open my application and notification still shows. Then I disconnect from wifi connection and the notification disappears, I connect again and notification appears again  as well ,as it should. Now if I remove my app from the overview and then disconnect from the wifi, my notification does not go, it sticks in the notification panel. Although this error is uncertain and occur in some phones and not in some.

I am posting my service code and main activity code.
Please suggest me a better approach to do this task.

MyService.java

```html
package com.sumatone.volsbbonetouch;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.SupplicantState;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

/**
 * Created by shalini on 31-01-2015.
 */
public class MyService extends Service {
    private boolean CHECK=true,tcheck=true;
    private Thread t1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final ShowNotification s=new ShowNotification(this);
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Service was created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    CHECK=checkConnection();
                    if (CHECK==true&&tcheck==true) {
                        Log.d("status", "connected");
                        s.notifyInstant();
                        tcheck=false;
                    }
                    else if (CHECK==false&&tcheck==false) {
                        Log.d("status", "disconnected");
                        s.remove();
                        tcheck=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        /*t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    checkConnection();
                    if (!CHECK) {
                        Log.d("status", "disconnected");
                        t1.notify();
                        try {
                            t2.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Service was started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t1.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }
    public boolean checkConnection() {
        /*final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if(wifi.isConnected())
        {
            Log.d("wifi",wifi.getExtraInfo());
            if(wifi.getExtraInfo().equalsIgnoreCase("\"VOLSBB\"")) {
                Log.d("wifistate","connected");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }*/
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            final WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            final SupplicantState supp= wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
            Log.d("wifi",wifiInfo.getSSID());
            if((wifiInfo.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase("\"VOLSBB\"")||wifiInfo.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase("\"VOLS\""))&&wifi.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("wifistate","connected");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Service was destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```html
package com.sumatone.volsbbonetouch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shalini on 29-01-2015.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String url="http://phc.prontonetworks.com/cgi-bin/authlogin?URI=http://www.msftncsi.com/redirect";
    EditText uname,password;
    TextView res;
    Button login,logout,slogin;
    List<NameValuePair> details;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SharedPreferences s;
    Authentication a;
    String u,p,toasttext,session;
    ImageView about;
    String service="ProntoAuthentication";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class))
        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        about=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.about);
        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        s= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        uname.setText(s.getString("prontousername",null));
        password.setText(s.getString("prontopassword",null));
        a= new Authentication(this);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        logout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        slogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.savelogin);
        res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        logout.setOnClickListener(this);
        slogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        about.setOnClickListener(this);
        session=s.getString("session","first");
        if(session.equals("first")){
            about.performClick();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=s.edit();
            editor.putString("session","used");
            editor.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == R.id.login) {
                if(checkConnection()) {
                    details = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    url = "http://phc.prontonetworks.com/cgi-bin/authlogin?URI=http://www.msftncsi.com/redirect";
                    u = uname.getText().toString();
                    p = password.getText().toString();
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", u));
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", p));
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serviceName", service));
                    new GetEvents().execute();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Not connected to Volsbb",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.logout) {
                if(checkConnection()) {
                    details = null;
                    url = "http://phc.prontonetworks.com/cgi-bin/authlogout";
                    new GetEvents().execute();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Not connected to Volsbb",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.savelogin) {
                if (checkConnection()) {
                    details = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    url = "http://phc.prontonetworks.com/cgi-bin/authlogin?URI=http://www.msftncsi.com/redirect";
                    u = uname.getText().toString();
                    p = password.getText().toString();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s.edit();
                    editor.putString("prontousername", u);
                    editor.putString("prontopassword", p);
                    editor.commit();
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", u));
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", p));
                    details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serviceName", service));
                    new GetEvents().execute();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected to Volsbb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if(v.getId()==R.id.about)
            {
                Intent i= new Intent(this,AboutDialog.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkConnection() {
        /*final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if(wifi.isConnected())
        {
            Log.d("wifi",wifi.getExtraInfo());
            if(wifi.getExtraInfo().equalsIgnoreCase("\"VOLSBB\"")) {
                Log.d("wifistate","connected");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }*/
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            final WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            Log.d("wifi",wifiInfo.getSSID());
            if(wifiInfo.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase("\"VOLSBB\"")) {
                Log.d("wifistate","connected");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Processing");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String valresponse = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST,details);
            Log.d("Response: ", ">" + valresponse);
            return valresponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            if(result.contains("Logout successful"))
                toasttext="Logged out";
            else if(result.contains("Successful Pronto Authentication"))
                toasttext="Logged in";
            else if(result.contains("There is no active session to logout"))
                toasttext="There is no active session";
            else if(result.contains("Sorry, please check your username and password"))
                toasttext="Invalid username/password";
            else if(result.contains("Sorry, your free access quota is over"))
                toasttext="Your free access qouta is over";
            else
                toasttext="Already Logged in";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toasttext,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return START_STICKY in onStartCommand() to keep the service running. START_STICKY tells the OS to recreate the service if it is killed for some reason (i.e., memory, manually killing the app).

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
      //Your service code

      return START_STICKY;
 }
```